# Tensorflow's placeholder initialization differs from tensorflow's constant initialization. Why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, initialization

I have written 2 functions that initialize **tensorflow**'s variables in different ways. I don't know why the results are different. Here is the first function using **placeholder** for initialization:

## First function

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def linear_function():
    np.random.seed(1)

    X = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float64, name='X')
    W = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float64, name='W')
    b = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float64, name='b')
    Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(W, X), b)

    sess = tf.Session()

    result = sess.run(Y, feed_dict={W:np.random.randn(4,3), X:np.random.randn(3,1), b:np.random.randn(4,1)})
    sess.close()
    return result
print( "result = " + str(linear_function()))
```

And the result is:

```
result = [[-1.98748544]
 [-2.76826248]
 [-0.78635415]
 [-2.77463846]]
```

## Second function

Second function uses `tf.constant` to initialize variables:

```
def linear_function():

    np.random.seed(1)

    X = tf.constant(np.random.randn(3,1), name ="X")
    W = tf.constant(np.random.randn(4,3), name ="X")
    b = tf.constant(np.random.randn(4,1), name ="X")
    Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(W,X), b)

    sess = tf.Session()
    result = sess.run(Y)

    sess.close()

    return result

print( "result = " + str(linear_function()))
```

Result:

```
result = [[-2.15657382]
 [ 2.95891446]
 [-1.08926781]
 [-0.84538042]]
```

What is the problem? Is it related to `np.random.seed(1)` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet, the `feed_dict` is:

```
{W:np.random.randn(4,3), X:np.random.randn(3,1), b:np.random.randn(4,1)}
```

So first a random value for `W` is produced, then for `X` and then for `b`. However, in the second snippet the random values are given in the order `X`, `W` and `b`. Since the order in which the random numbers are generated is not the same, the values differ. If for example you change the order adequately in the `feed_dict` in the first snippet you will get the same result as the second one:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def linear_function():
    np.random.seed(1)

    X = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float64, name='X')
    W = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float64, name='W')
    b = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float64, name='b')
    Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(W, X), b)

    sess = tf.Session()

    result = sess.run(Y, feed_dict={X:np.random.randn(3,1), W:np.random.randn(4,3), b:np.random.randn(4,1)})
    sess.close()
    return result

print( "result = " + str(linear_function()))
```

Output:

```
result = [[-2.15657382]
 [ 2.95891446]
 [-1.08926781]
 [-0.84538042]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Why np.random is so troublesome :(

Comment: @Muser Essentially every pseudorandom number generator works like that. You can set it to a well-known initial state with `seed`, so if you do exactly the same random operations after that you will get the same results. However, different sequences of random operations (even if it is the same set of operations in a different order) will always (or should always) result in different values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I can use np.random.seed properly.